# How to use Marionette web driver in robotframework after upgrade browser to Firefox 47

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, robotframework

I was using robotframework Selenium2Library to run test in Firefox. 
As I upgrade Firefox to version 47, I found Firefox will crash at the beginning when Firefox starts. The issue is in github issue list as follow link:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110.

So I turned to using Marionette as issue comments suggested, but the result is not good(the error shows: WebDriverException: Message: connection refused, and using selenium directly won't help). Also from selenium2Library guide page, it tells desired_capabilities will not work for local webdriver.

So my questions are:

1. How can I setup a local Marionette webdriver instance inside Selenium and pass to robot for further testing operations?
2. If there is a way to keep using Firefox 47 without webdriver support?

I followed instructions here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

in a python file:

```
def returnFirefoxCapabilities(marionetteBinaryPath):
    firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
    firefox_capabilities['binary'] = marionetteBinaryPath
    return firefox_capabilities
```

and in robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library  #build-in library
*** Test Case ***
try marionette
   ${firefox_capabilities}=     returnFirefoxCapabilities    path/wires
   open browser  url=www.google.com    desired_capabilities=${firefox_capabilities}
```

Comment: I was wandering, is phantomjs a good option for robot? ( Have read some web pages,  said phantomjs is not supported directly, so every keyword need be created manually)

Comment: Support for PhantomJS was added a long time ago. You might need to use the keyword Create Webdriver depending on your setup, but Open Browser might work as well. I cannot say whether or not it is a good option though as I have used only "real" browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium2Library does not support passing in desired capabilities for local webdrivers. But you can change the default capabilities for Firefox and it will apply to all future webdriver instances for a given browser type until the interpreter (Python) exits. I was able to run simple tests with Firefox 47, Selenium 2.53.5, and Geckodriver 0.8.0.

```
${ff default caps}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX    sys,selenium.webdriver
Set To Dictionary    ${ff default caps}    marionette=${True}
Open Browser    https://www.stackoverflow.com    ff
```

You asked how to pass in a webdriver instance. This appeared to me as an X-Y problem, so I did not answer that question. Please ask a separate question if needed.